# Utility rooms having gas

Tags: plumbing, gas

I am asking about utility rooms with gas. My main question is about the door in a dwelling. I have seen doors from city to city all have AHJ that have their own way of doing doors. Some doors are fire-rated ,hollow core doors with sheet metal on the inside was ok. Then next wants louvered door for air for gas. **What is the law for doors?** And does the size of the room  matter on door type for a dwelling.

Comment: What, precisely, does this utility room house? I suspect the variations you see are partially due to that...

Comment: The room is 6 wide by 10 long. Elec panel, water pump  gas furnace gas hot water. And the variations are each  AHJ way.  Some doors fire rated dont have anything bad to say about that. The point im after is air. Some want a total louvered  W[ll gas shut off dew to lack of air?